# Is it possible to replace a part of value from captured correlation in Loadrunner?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I am correlating json response, but from the captured json I need to replace a value with some different text.
For example - captured response is as below and saved to "corr_json"variable:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": JSON:API paints my bikeshed!,
      "body": "The shortest article. Ever.",
      "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
      "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": {"id": "42", "type": "people"}
      }
    }
```

from this I need to replace string
`API paints my bikeshed`
with text `Performance Testing` and pass to next request, so the json to be pass as below:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Performance Testing",
      "body": "The shortest article. Ever.",
      "created": "2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z",
      "updated": "2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": {"id": "42", "type": "people"}
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to do this in Loadrunner?

Answer (score 1):

Check [lr_json_replace](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/2020_SP2-SP3/help/function_reference/FuncRef.htm#FuncRef/c_vuser/lrFr_lr_json_replace.htm%3FTocPath%3DUtility%2520Functions%2520and%2520C%2520Language%2520Reference%7CUtility%2520Functions%253A%2520C%2520Language%2520(lr_)%7CAlphabetical%2520Listing%7C_____48) api provided by LoadRunner.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your protocol in use, the language of LoadRunner is either C, C#, C++, VB, or JavaScript.  Use the sting processing capabilities of your language, combined with your programming skills to reformat the text in question to include your tag.

Hint, you might consider two correlations on the returned data, one which begins with the first curly brace and ends with '"title":' with the second beginning with '"title":' and ending with the '\t\t}\r\t}' (if I am reading the text right) structure.   Then you could simply sprintf() in C to pack a few strings (corr1+ your tag+corr2+ end structure) together to hit your mark.